# what does net.getPeerCount() give?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to sync to Ethereum mainnet.

when attach the running geth to console and execute `admin.peers`
I get below output

```
[{
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "147fd0986cdba18279e309149290431e874a2ff0d72a18d2a81bb02d2bf0b65456b7419eb21800516177767b5037449950a9ad7f3d06c910df760c89d76c9ff1",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:59778",
      remoteAddress: "71.236.189.250:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "1bba662f185f45cd68465ee3b340ed107a1bc309c6e7f3ad4634e69fa5f864d4daf1a1188cf2cd38659027aee5d33daecf9d04f1a003b136cfa3605f22ca590b",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/windows-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:59736",
      remoteAddress: "85.72.54.240:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "4630000bc70b789a45b58beba3944c050ac9998e55db40b6e8ea5df1da95bf1452863c3271f48341854a0de4f1a5ce6578c424ab04af510d68b1745125d26dac",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/linux-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:50086",
      remoteAddress: "189.27.174.216:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "a4c00346511940ed69d408fb8801efd5ad2822985817c6f5f534591463befc00ba21c23a76c19e4ee9bb91b215b02300b9b7d14105711a0a4f75951f89e148a9",
    name: "Geth/v1.8.0-unstable-a139041d/linux-amd64/go1.9.2",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:38442",
      remoteAddress: "46.29.13.213:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "ab3662c8e1b62b36444a50f87af14e7668a6afcf15f4d7a1fd3bb160dc945360378edb6ab63a7d518d26372c89fb559fd37f00010f9d090c2ecfdc303874a3f9",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/windows-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:35660",
      remoteAddress: "95.43.38.32:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "d1254b0d24582469d3f0e8a4692f27155ad40d46ebc2c74a700d94e68d9f8fc903022140661185aa2367f5738ea9b75066e66f83076198e12643257701668467",
    name: "Geth/v1.8.0-unstable-3a5a5599/linux-amd64/go1.7.4",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.10.25.218:33204",
      remoteAddress: "144.76.60.212:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}]
```

and if I run `net.getPeerCount()`, I get below output

```
    > net.getPeerCount()
      undefined
    >
```

I was hoping it will give me the count of the peers which were output of `admin.peers`

Comment: "This property is read only and returns the number of connected peers." https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3netpeercount

Comment: So isn't  the output of admin.peers give me the list and details of connected peers?

Comment: It is, but try calling `net.peerCount` without the parenthesis

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ This is what i get If I call it without parenthesis - `> net.getPeerCount
function(callback)
>`

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, to see the property value use `net.peerCount`, not net.getPeerCount

Comment: but I want to know what does ` net.getPeerCount` give?

Comment: They both return the same thing, but getPeerCount is asynchronous so it requires a call back function to execute when it completes   web3.net.getPeerCount(callback(error, result){ ... })

Answer (score 0):

`net.peerCount()` is a command which returns number of Peers connected to your node.